# How can I connect two monitors?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have this notebook: ASUS F556UR and i would like to have two external monitors connected to it. One has a HDMI interface and the other uses VGA. The problem is that the two ports on the laptop are way too close to connect both VGA and HDMI cable. Also note that i've tried with a USB type C docking station that, unfortunately, i cannot use because this laptop does not support media casting via that port. What can i do? Can you address me to somewhere i can buy a slim (means with no security screws on both sides) VGA cable or extender?

Edit: I know i can "simply" cut away screws from a standard VGA cable, but at the moment i would like to know if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Are you sure your notebook can even power both ports at once? Quite a few cannot.

Comment: I'm not sure about this because i cannot connect both of the cables, so i have not tested it. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you tell us what processor your specific model has, and if it has discrete graphics, what model that is too? It's quite probable that this is a design choice to prevent both from being connected at once - because they're not both supported at once. Other options exist (like a USB to VGA adapter, though _not_ USB-C Alt Mode, as you've discovered).

Comment: Processor is an Intel Core i7-7500U, 3.5GHz. It also has a graphic card installed, it an NVidia GeForce 930MX. Are USB to VGA cables a real thing that can help me achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a trip into your local computer store to see what cables are available.
At least then you could pick up a cheap VGA cable to modify(cut off the screws) for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I searched through the [manual for your laptop](https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/F556UR/HelpDesk_Manual/) and it doesn't state anything about external monitors at all. The fact that they are so close together that you can't plug both in tells me that they didn't intend for you to do so. I would do what you mentioned and cut the screws to see if it will work. Why take the time to try and find a cable that will fit side by side with the HDMI when your not even sure it will work.

You can also do what Attie mentioned and check the processor documentation directly since it likely has integrated graphics. This is certainly the more traditional method of determining how many monitors you can use.